# Replace specific Elements in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say i have a array in ruby for example:

```
arr = ['M','X','C','Y','C']
```

How can i replace the elements with the value `'M'` and `'Y'` with `'1'`

and replace `'X'` with `'2'`

and last `'C'` with `'5'`

So that at the end my array is transformed to:

```
['1','2','5','1','5']
```

I know there are several ways i tried for example a case-loop:

```
arr.map { |i| case i 
  when ['X'].include? i then '2'
  when ['M','Y'].include? i then '1'
  when ['C'].include? i then '5'
end }
```

But that somehow gave me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
... end }
```

What did i wrong or what could i use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a hash and [`Array#map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map-21):

```
mapping = {'M' => '1', 'Y' => '1', 'X' => '2', 'C' => '5'}
arr = ['M','X','C','Y','C']
arr.map! { |c| mapping[c] }
# => ["1", "2", "5", "1", "5"]
```

**UPDATE**

As Stefan suggested, you can also use [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
arr = ['M','X','C','Y','C']
mapping = {'M' => '1', 'Y' => '1', 'X' => '2', 'C' => '5'}
mapping.values_at(*arr)
# => ["1", "2", "5", "1", "5"]
```

Comment: Be aware, that using `map!` will change array itself. If you need to preserve array use `map` method instead.

Comment: @Pavan, Adding parentheses after `include?` will solve the error (to remove ambiguity). `p arr.map { |i| case when ['X'].include?(i) then '2' when ['M','Y'].include?(i) then '1' when ['C'].include?(i) then '5' end }`

Comment: Another option is `mapping.values_at(*arr)`

Comment: @Stefan, Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer to include your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your error, you would use a `case` statement like this:

```
arr = ['M','X','C','Y','C']
arr.map { |i|
  case i
  when 'X' then '2'
  when 'M', 'Y' then '1'
  when 'C' then '5'
  end
}
#=> ["1", "2", "5", "1", "5"]
```

The block is called for each element and the element is passed into the block as `i`.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is always a string, you can do the following:

```
arr = %W(M X C Y C)
arr.join.tr("MYXC", "1125").split("")
```

Comment: Nice solution quirrel

Comment: @anusha No.. In this case. *array->string->array*.. Not needed to much intermediate object creations.. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24076168/2767755) perfect.

Comment: It is possible that if OP is using arrays of single characters, that perhaps he wants a string? I don't know enough about the problem to suggest it outright, but my answer is atleast a hint that there are methods on strings that are amenable to his needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Module#const_get](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-const_get), like so:

```
M,X,C,Y = '1','2','5','1'
arr = ['M','X','C','Y','C']

arr.map { |e| Object.const_get(e) }
  #=> ["1", "2", "5", "1", "5"]
```

(Not advocating, just saying.)